# Dimensions and fact tables using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm supposed to create a dimension and fact tables with SQL Server 2008 using TSQL, but I got the following error message : `Unknown object type 'DIMENSION' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.`and my code is :

> CREATE DIMENSION dim_date
>
> LEVEL jour IS t_date.a_date
>
> LEVEL jour_du_mois IS
>   t_date.a_jourmois
>
> LEVEL jour_de_annee IS
>   t_date.a_jourannee
>
> LEVEL semaine_de_annee IS
>   t_date.a_semaineannee
>
> LEVEL mois IS t_date.a_mois
>
> LEVEL annee IS t_date.a_annee
>
> HIERARCHY date_relative (
>
> jour CHILD OF
>
> jour_du_mois CHILD OF
>
> mois CHILD OF
>
> annee
>
> )
>
> HIERARCHY date_absolue (
>
> jour CHILD OF
>
> jour_de_annee CHILD OF
>
> semaine_de_annee CHILD OF
>
> annee
>
> )
>
> ;

I have already created the table named t_date.

Please if someone can help me to do that.

Comment: This looks like Oracle SQL rather than T-SQL. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes this work in ORACLE but I want create the same with SQLServer.

Comment: oh! You want someone to write your code for you!

Comment: No men. I already said that I want someone to help me not to do the work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the many areas where Oracle and SQL Server take completely different approaches to the same problem.

The SQL Server database engine has no direct equivalent of the Oracle [CREATE DIMENSION](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5006.htm) statement, and there is no way to define one using the T-SQL language; instead, the SQL Server product includes a seperate OLAP engine - [SQL Server Analysis Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/analysis-services.aspx).

SQL Server OLAP dimension and cube definitions are created through the [Business Intelligence Development Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767.aspx) - they are stored in a repository independent of the SQL Serve database engine.

You can define tables in the database engine, and add dimensional data to them, but you don't get all the features of a `DIMENSION` in Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Write `[Dimension]`, it is a [reserved word in MSSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144780%28SQL.90%29.aspx)